# iCal Creating Time Offset

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook, icalendar

When trying to create an iCal file I get a very strange issue that I cannot trace. The following is the code used and an example of an event that is set to start at 08:00 and end at 11:00. The file creates with relevant information, but when tryting to add it to Outlook an hour has been added to the end time.

```
DateTime eventDate = DateTime.Parse("19/06/2014");
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Parse("09:00:00");
DateTime endTime = DateTime.Parse("11:00:00");
string location = "Test Location";
string title = "Test Title";

context.Response.ContentType = "text/x-vcalendar";
string filename = String.Format("attachment; filename={0}.ics", eventname.Replace(" ", "-"));
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", filename);

context.Response.Write("BEGIN:VCALENDAR" + Environment.NewLine);
context.Response.Write("VERSION:2.0" + Environment.NewLine);
context.Response.Write("METHOD:PUBLISH" + Environment.NewLine);

context.Response.Write("BEGIN:VTIMEZONE" + Environment.NewLine);
context.Response.Write("TZID:Europe/London" + Environment.NewLine);
context.Response.Write("X-LIC-LOCATION:Europe/London" + Environment.NewLine);
context.Response.Write("BEGIN:DAYLIGHT" + Environment.NewLine);
context.Response.Write("TZOFFSETFROM:+0000" + Environment.NewLine);
context.Response.Write("TZOFFSETTO:+0100" + Environment.NewLine);
context.Response.Write("TZNAME:BST" + Environment.NewLine);
context.Response.Write("DTSTART:19700329T010000" + Environment.NewLine);
context.Response.Write("RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=-1SU" + Environment.NewLine);
context.Response.Write("END:DAYLIGHT" + Environment.NewLine);
context.Response.Write("BEGIN:STANDARD" + Environment.NewLine);
context.Response.Write("TZOFFSETFROM:+0100" + Environment.NewLine);
context.Response.Write("TZOFFSETTO:+0000" + Environment.NewLine);
context.Response.Write("TZNAME:GMT" + Environment.NewLine);
context.Response.Write("DTSTART:19701025T020000" + Environment.NewLine);
context.Response.Write("RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=10;BYDAY=-1SU" + Environment.NewLine);
context.Response.Write("END:STANDARD" + Environment.NewLine);
context.Response.Write("END:VTIMEZONE" + Environment.NewLine);

context.Response.Write("BEGIN:VEVENT" + Environment.NewLine);
context.Response.Write("ORGANIZER:MAILTO: test@domain.com" + Environment.NewLine);
context.Response.Write("UID: test2@domain.com" + Environment.NewLine);            
context.Response.Write("DTSTART:" + startDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ") + Environment.NewLine);
context.Response.Write("DTEND:" + GetMeetingEndDate(startDate, endDate).ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ") + Environment.NewLine);
context.Response.Write("DTSTAMP:" + DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ") + Environment.NewLine);
context.Response.Write("SUMMARY:" + subject + Environment.NewLine);
context.Response.Write("DESCRIPTION:" + description + Environment.NewLine);
context.Response.Write("LAST-MODIFIED:" + DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ") + Environment.NewLine);
context.Response.Write("PRIORITY:5" + Environment.NewLine);
context.Response.Write("LOCATION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:" + location + Environment.NewLine);
context.Response.Write("CLASS:PUBLIC" + Environment.NewLine);
context.Response.Write("END:VEVENT" + Environment.NewLine);

context.Response.Write("END:VCALENDAR");
```

The outcome of this is for the appointment to be added to Outlook with a start time of 09:00 and an end time of **12:00**. The end time has increased by one hour.

Please note that the code about is intended for British/GMT use.

I have debugged this procedure and checked all the dates as they are being set and everything is correct. Is there anything that I am missing with this? I really don't want to have to force a reduction in the end hour just so it adds properly to Outlook.

**Edit:**

The following is the GetMeetingEndDate function.

```
DateTime GetMeetingEndDate(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        DateTime newDate = new DateTime();
        if (endDate < startDate)
        {
            newDate = endDate.AddHours(12);
        }
        else if (endDate == startDate)
        {
            newDate = startDate.AddDays(1).AddHours(-1);
        }
        else
        {
            newDate = endDate;
        }
        return newDate;
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: What does `GetMeetingEndDate` function is doing? Can you show us its implementation?

Comment: I have edited the main question with the implementation of the `GetMeetingEndDate` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below code:-

```
context.Response.Write("DTSTART:" + startDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ") + Environment.NewLine);
context.Response.Write("DTEND:" + GetMeetingEndDate(startDate, endDate).ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ") + Environment.NewLine);
```

the `DTSTART` is set to value `startDate.ToUniversalTime()` whereas in function `GetMeetingEndDate` the dates are passed without converting into `UTC`. Because of this `startdate` is always correct but iCal is treating your local `enddate` as UTC date. That might be causing the problem of adding extra hour. The solution is to change the below code block as

```
context.Response.Write("DTEND:" + GetMeetingEndDate(startDate.ToUniversalTime(), endDate.ToUniversalTime()).ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ") + Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: That fixed it, thank you very much! Kicking myself that I didn't spot that before! Accepted as answer. Thanks again!